# switched from vbs to js, amateur

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I'm an amateur programmer. I just switched from VBS to JS, I was
trying to convert numbers to text and I'm stuck and have no
idea what to do.

```
    <html>
<body>

<script language="javascript">
var x = prompt("Please enter a number");

var str=x.toString();
var i;

for i <5, i++;{


var c=parseInt(str,i,1);

}

function main(mainvalue,addstring) {

if mainvalue=1 {
var a=(" one"); 
}elseif mainvalue=2 {
var a=(" two"); 
}elseif mainvalue=3 { 
var a=(" three") ;
}elseif mainvalue=4 {
var a=(" four"); 
}elseif mainvalue=5 {
var a=(" five"); 
}elseif mainvalue=6 {
var a=(" six"); 
}elseif mainvalue=7 {
var a=(" seven") ;
}elseif mainvalue=8 {
var a=(" eight"); 
}elseif mainvalue=9 {
var a=(" nine") ;
}   
main=(a + addstring);

}

var thousands=parseInt(c/1000);



var strvalue = main( thousands, " thousand");

document.write(main(thousands," thousand" ));

var c=c-(thousands*1000) ;
var hundreds=parseInt(c/100);
document.write(" and ");


var strvalue1 = main( hundreds, " hundred") ;
document.write(main(hundreds," hundred"));

var c=c-(hundreds*100);
var tens=parseInt(c/10);



var strvalue2 = main( tens, "ty");
document.write(main(tens,"ty

var c=c-(tens*10);
var ones=parseInt(c);

var strvalue3 = main(ones,"");
document.write(main(ones,""));


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest you open the console and start debugging little by little, there are many errors in the code above: non-closed quotes, missing parenthesis, incorrect syntax, wrong keywords...

Comment: I figured the syntax for for loop was incorrect so i did "
for (i=0; i<5, i++;{

 
 var c=parseInt(str,i,1);
  
}
" 

I am not able to debugg it, this is my first time using js and its causing me troubles. 
I can do this easily in vbs but i need to do it in js this time

Comment: Check out https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It is important as well to check out the docs on the basics: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt parseInt takes two params, a string and an optional radix (base) param. Of course, JS is ducktyped, so you could just as easily put a "+" before the string or multiply by one.

Comment: @BTC can you rewrite some parts of it and help?

Comment: JSHint or JSLint will be your friend.